# Changing GMT to EST for Time in Crystal Reports

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

Right now all of my times on my reports are in GMT.  Anybody know how to convert this into EST?

Comment: you mean, how to subtract 5 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sell a C++, User-Function Library (UFL) that accomplishes this task.  See http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?page_id=14 for more information.

Otherwise, take a look at the ShiftDateTime() function.